# Qgis2Web changing canvas size

Tags: qgis, qgis2web, mapcanvas

I am using QGIS 3.28. I exported my project using Qgis2Web plugin. The base map is OSM. But it gives me the entire world map. Is there a way to limit the base map to specific country/area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In QGIS, zoom to the area/country you want to view on the web map. Under the appearance tab in the Export to web map dialog, look at the Scale/Zoom options and use Extent as Canvas extent:

[image]

Here you go:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @GfroGIS